# Allow only three numeric values ​or characters in the text box

Tags: textbox, numbers, vb6, character

I want to make a Text Box control accept only three numbers or characters
How can I do this in VB6?

Comment: If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon your exact requirements there are a number of ways to approach this problem.  If you only want to allow up to 3 *characters* do this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Text1.MaxLength = 3
End Sub
```

If you only want to allow up to 3 *numbers* do this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Text1.MaxLength = 3
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   'allow numbers and backspace
   If Not (KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57) And Not KeyAscii = 8 Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub
```

If you only want to allow exactly 3 numbers do this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Text1.MaxLength = 3
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   'allow numbers and backspace
   If Not (KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57) And Not KeyAscii = 8 Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
   If Len(Text1.Text) <> 3 Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

These examples should get you started in solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you, you have helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> "only three numbers or characters"

Is that **exactly** three or **max** three? The Textbox control has a `.MaxLength` property, setting this to "3" allows for three or less characters. But a fixed exact length check can easily added to the method below.

Something like this:

```
Public Function ValidateTextbox(ByVal txt As TextBox, ByVal allowedChars As String, Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = True) As Boolean

   Dim i As Long, j As Long
   Dim sText As String, s As String
   Dim bolValidChar As Boolean
   
   sText = txt.Text
   
   For i = 1 To Len(sText)
      ' Assume False. When the checked character from the textbox
      ' matches any allowed character, this will be set to True
      bolValidChar = False
      s = Mid$(sText, i, 1)
      For j = 1 To Len(allowedChars)
         ' Case-sensitive?
         If caseSensitive = True Then
            If s = Mid$(allowedChars, j, 1) Then
               bolValidChar = True
               Exit For
            End If
         Else
            If LCase$(s) = LCase$(Mid$(allowedChars, j, 1)) Then
               bolValidChar = True
               Exit For
            End If
         End If
      Next j
      
      If bolValidChar = False Then
         ' We've got at least one invalid character -> get outa here!
         ValidateTextbox = False
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next i
   
   ValidateTextbox = bolValidChar

End Function
```

Where you called it from, e.g. the textbox' `Change` or `LostFocus` event or somewhere else in your code, depends upon your needs/application design.

```
Private Sub txtTest_Change()

   Dim sValidChars As String
   
   ' sValidChars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   sValidChars = "0123456789abcdefg"
   
   If ValidateTextbox(txtTest, sValidChars) = False Then
      Debug.Print "Invalid character!"
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you, you have helped me a lot.